# Google Docs table of contents links are wrong in PDF

Tags: pdf, google-drive

Me and my school partner use Google Docs for our school reports so we can write in the same document at the same time. Works fine.

We normally download the report as a PDF and hand it in. Today when downloading it as a PDF I tried the table of contents links that it creates when you create the table of contents, but then it linked to the web version instead of linking to the specific title in the PDF.

It used to work. Does anyone know if im doing something wrong, or?

Comment: @dhojgaard - The report always linked to the web content.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm pretty sure that is not true... Last year this time i handed in a report also written in google docs and downloaded as a PDF, and i checked that it was working properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Docs actualy makes the table of contents in a correct manner, BUT, it's PDF translation is wrong. If you convert it to some other document format and use something like Word or LibreOffice to turn it to a pdf it'll work. Third party pdf converters also might work. I know that's not a great consolation, but it's a known bug.

Why are they not doing anything about it... No idea. They could just convert libre office's code in the worst case.

Comment: Any references you could add? Thanks.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/gXsXq3zz7ak%5B1-25-true%5D